# How to put data in next line in a table in Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, prawn

I am using prawn gem and i have this in my show.pdf.prawn

```
pdf.text "Customer:  #{@customer.name}", :size => 20, :style => :bold, :align => :center

pdf.move_down 10


billing = @customer.billing_addresses.map do |item|
      [
        'Billing Address', "#{item.billing_address}",
        'City', "#{item.city}",
        'Pincode', "#{item.pincode}",
        'Country', "#{item.country.country_name}",
        'State', "#{item.state.state_name}",
        'Tel. Work', "#{item.tel_work}",
      ]
    end

    pdf.table billing,
    :border_width => 0,
    :font_size => 11,
    :position => :center,
    :column_widths => { 0 => 200, 1 => 300},
    :row_widths => { 0 => 500, 1 => 500}
```

and m getting the this error

> Prawn::Errors::CannotFit

What seems to be the Problem? how can i fix it? I went through Documentation of Prawn Errors and it says "CannotFit Raised when Prawn is asked to draw something into a too-small box " WHich i am not able to understand... i think problem is everything is coming in one row...how to make it display in separate rows???, Any guidance would be helpful, Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I recommend you stop fighting with Prawn, and try PdfKit instead. Working with Prawn is awkward and painful at best, and working with PdfKit a breath of fresh air.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Steve, will go with pdfkit.

Comment: bharath, what is your intended layout?  You have 12 columns per row in your current layout, and spec'ing the two of them at 200 and 300 isn't leaving much room for the other 10 (Prawn defaults to 75 if I recall correctly)... and setting a row width of 500 won't work.  Are you trying for two columns in your table (label in column 1, value in column 2)? Or something else?

Comment: Actually i was planning for 2 col in each row.....i dunno how to do that....Name and attribute one row...next row again name and attribute...but i am getting everyting in one row...as u said tweleve col.. :(